# typescript implementing interfaces in classes and assigning it to a object with a type interface

Tags: typescript, class, interface, interface-implementation

I am new to typescript and came across classes which implement interface. I know that a class can add properties that the interface didn't have, but it must contain all the properties the interface has. My problem is when i am making a new object from my class with a type of a certain interface, it gets confusing.
I saw on the site of tutorial teachers, the following code

```
   interface IPerson {
        name: string;
        display():void;
    }

    interface IEmployee {
        empCode: number;
    }

    class Employee implements IPerson, IEmployee {
        empCode: number;
        name: string;

        constructor(empcode: number, name:string) {
            this.empCode = empcode;
            this.name = name;
        }

        display(): void {
            console.log("Name = " + this.name +  ", Employee Code = " + this.empCode);
        }
    }

    let per:IPerson = new Employee(100, "Bill");
    per.display(); // Name = Bill, Employee Code = 100

    let emp:IEmployee = new Employee(100, "Bill");
    emp.display(); //Compiler Error: Property 'display' does not exist on type IEmployee'
```

If after `let per:IPerson = new Employee(100, "Bill");` i would `console.log(per.empCode)` there will be a compiler error saying

> Property 'empCode' does not exist on type 'IPerson'.

So why does per.display() manage to log the empCode even when the type is Iperson amd that does not have a empCode Property. Please can you help me understand the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard behavior in an object oriented programming language. Basically when you do:

```
let per:IPerson = new Employee(100, "Bill");
```

The compiler only cares about the type of `per` which is `IPerson`. `IPerson` does not have the property `empCode`. Even though we know it is an `Employee` and this does have a `empCode` property the compiler can not know this for certain!

When you do `per.display()` the `empCode` is accessible because at that point you will be inside the scope of the `Employee` class.

Comment: Agree to the answer. Another suggestion could be using the addition of `IPerson + IEmployee`.
i.e:

`interface IPersonEmployee {
        name: string;
        display():void;
        empCode: number;
    }
.....
let per:IPersonEmployee = new IPersonEmployee(100,'Bill', 200);`

Comment: @AlbertoAM don't created a 'merged' interface by redefining the properties again. Simply do: `interface IPersonEmployee extends IPerson, IEmployee {}`. Also your code sample is broken: you cannot instantiate an interface as you are doing here. That's a basic property of interfaces.